# mvc3 architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

i want to develop a simple CMS.

i want to add the ability to add modules to the CMS.

1. what need to be the architecture for
   such a CMS?

   a solution and then a mvc project
   for the site and another for the
   admin? or one project with area for
   the admin?

in mvc each of my modules will have a controller,model and views. if i will put all in one project, then i will mix of all module ,each module will be in 3 folders (controller,model and views).

how i need to arrange them so my code will be nice and clean?

Comment: try 3 seperate projects. 1 web, 1 service and 1 data

Comment: @Mclean, but the mix will be the same even more...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only separating by type of user, you can surely (and easily) include in one project. all of your Admin controllers should have [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] on them to limit them only for the admin. Mixing them is fine, other applications mix user roles in an application on a regular basis, just limit the difference by security (and dont use url restrictions in your web.config - use the [Authorize] attribute on your controllers instead!!
If you expect the differences in both applications to be *huge* then you can separate into another project, but I'm imagining you can get very good reuse by including them in the same project.

How to architect this is a very very broad question. For a basic project some include everything all in one project. I prefer to break out all my models and data access code into a separate project and try to code to interfaces as much as possible for unit testing purposes. I think that is all a bit beyond the scope of the posting here though. To start - work with the mentioned attribute and I think you will develop. Start unit testing early and I think that will help steer you into the right direction. Also read up on dependency injectiom , unit, ninject, etc for ways to dynamically bind to your implementation classes as this makes your unit test go quite a bit smoother as well.

Comment: @Tuliper, i could use  [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] even if i don't use asp.net membership?

Comment: thats right.. you just need to make sure IPrincipal is there for an authenticated user.  check out these 2 SO posts
http://bit.ly/jl13bc 
http://bit.ly/mErqMZ